# Magento 2 tier price is not showing with tax

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento2.3, magento2.2, tax-calculation

```
<?php 
if($_product->getTierPrice()){
    foreach ($tierPrice as $key => $value) {
        $qty = (int)$value['price_qty'];
        $price = $value['price'];
        $formattedTierPrice = $this->helper('Magento\Framework\Pricing\Helper\Data')->currency(number_format($price, 2), true, false);
        $savePercentage = round(100 - ( (100 / $_product->getPrice())* $price) ) ."%";
        echo "<div style='font-weight: 600;background: #f5f5f5;padding: 5px; display: block; margin: 20px 0px 0px'>"."Buy $qty for "."<span style='color: #000;font-size: 16px;'>" . $formattedTierPrice . "</span>"." each and save ".$savePercentage."<br>"."</div>";
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php 

if($_product->getTierPrice()){
    $tierPrice = $_product->getTierPrice();
    $regular_price_of_custom = $_product->getPriceInfo()->getPrice('regular_price')->getAmount()->getValue();
    foreach ($tierPrice as $key => $value) {
        $regular_price_of_custom_tot = "";
        $qty = (int)$value['price_qty']; 
        $price = $value['price'];
        $savePercentage = round(100 - ( (100 / $_product->getPrice())* $price) ) ."%";
        $regular_price_of_custom_tot = $regular_price_of_custom - (($regular_price_of_custom * $savePercentage) / 100);
        $formattedTierPrice = $this->helper('Magento\Framework\Pricing\Helper\Data')->currency(number_format($regular_price_of_custom_tot, 2), true, false);

        echo "<div style='font-weight: 600;background: #f5f5f5;padding: 5px; display: block; margin: 20px 0px 0px'>"."Buy $qty for "."<span style='color: #000;font-size: 16px;'>" . $formattedTierPrice . "</span>"." each and save ".$savePercentage."<br>"."</div>";

    }
}
```